# C# Winform: Automatically Login to a report server using Webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, windows-security

I want to access an asp.net report server using a windows forms application (specifically the Web Browser Control).

I am already able to load the page (via button click), however, the web browser still prompts me to enter the username and password of the report server.

How do I automatically set the username and password of the report server such that when I load the Web browser, Windows Security will not prompt the user to input the username and password?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following and it will work for you

```
        Uri u = new Uri("http://192.168.0.91");
        UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder(u);
        ub.UserName = "admin";
        ub.Password = "admin";
        webBrowser1.Url = ub.Uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmetically, you can get elements for username and password input using `WebBrowser.Document` and input the values and also need to invoke the login button.
There is simple example for login,

```
//After loading web page contents into browser get input as
private void FillAuthentication(string username, string password)
{
    if (_mainDialog.WebBrowser.Document == null) return;
    var tagsColl = _mainDialog.WebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
    foreach (GeckoElement currentTag in tagsColl)
    {
        if (currentTag.TagName.Equals("email"))
            currentTag.SetAttribute("value", username);
        if (currentTag.TagName.Equals("pass"))
            currentTag.SetAttribute("value", password);
    }
}
```

Now perform Click

```
private void ClickLoginButton()
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            if (_mainDialog.WebBrowser.Document == null) return;
            var col = _mainDialog.WebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (var element in col.Cast<HtmlElement>().Where(element => element.Name.Trim().Equals("") || element.Name.Trim().Equals("login")))
            {
                element.InvokeMember("click");
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }));
}
```

After this you also need to check by elements if there is any authentication error.

NOTE: You need to study whole login page html source, so you will be able to get required elements. Secondly, download & import [Skybound.Gecko.dll](https://code.google.com/p/geckofx/downloads/detail?name=Skybound.GeckoFX.bin.v1.9.1.0.zip&can=2&q=).

Comment: i tried your FillAuthentication method,  and it returns an error: "_mainDialog does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @wowomg Replace `_mainDialog.WebBrowser` with your own webBrowser object in which you loaded login page of site.

Comment: alright, what about GeckoElement? It also was not instantiated

Comment: @wowomg Sorry, I didn't mention about it. I have edited my answer, please check it

Comment: by the way, the login prompt of the report server is not embedded in the html page.  It is a windows security pop up which asks for the username and password. I doubt this would work

Comment: @wowomg I don't know exactly about the site which you are using but I did it for login to facebook site programmatically and also did many other operations.

Comment: @wowomg If you are able to get html source of login page or dialog, you can do it very easily, seriously, we can get html source of any dialog or web page very easily.